# How to create parallel edge loops

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I want to create a tiled floor look.
I'm hoping there is a way I can do that by making an square shaped loop of vertices inside each of these squares.

But then again that would mean I'd have to do that for every single square...

Is there an easier way to do this? please let me know.

[image]

[image]

I want something to the effect of this

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Inset tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?highlight=inset) (keyboard shortcut <kbd>i</kbd>)

Set it to **individual**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the steps :

1. Select all face in *Edit Mode*, and change your *Pivot point* to *Individual origins*
   hit the *Extrude individual* as highlighted below

[image]

Extrude slightly up to z axis

[image]

Hit <kbd>S</kbd> on the keyboard and drag mouse inside to scale it down

[image]

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a single tile, or a small selection of tiles and then use the array modifier to create a grid of them.

If you wanted to further randomise them, the easiest way, but perhaps not the quickest would be to then apply the array modifier and use proportional editing to grab and move various corners and edges.